# Access Fragment from Activity

Tags: android, android-fragments

I want to access my Fragment inside my Activity, but everything I tried so far results in the fragment being null. I tried doing this in my Activity:

```
FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
Fragment frag = fm.findFragmentById(R.id.fragment);
WeatherActivityFragment wf = (WeatherActivityFragment) frag;
```

My fragment looks like this:

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/fragment"
android:name="nl.marcovp.weather.WeatherActivityFragment"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:layout="@layout/fragment_weather" />
```

The layout used looks like this:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/container_fragment"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingLeft="16dp"
android:paddingRight="16dp"
android:paddingBottom="90dp"
android:paddingTop="16dp"
tools:context="nl.marcovp.weather.WeatherActivityFragment"
tools:showIn="@layout/activity_weather">
```

I can't seem to figure out what I'm doing wrong here.

Comment: how are you adding fragment?

Comment: @NaveenDew In do setContentView(R.layout.activity_weather) on the onCreate method of my Activity an have tools:showIn="@layout/activity_weather in the fragments xml

Comment: what error are you getting? your code is working fine ...